# 'undefined' error when trying to access Firebase DB using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

This is what I have saved in DB
[image]

This is my code which I used to try to access the data.

The goal is to get the value of the 1st `id`

```
var ref = db.ref("server/events/data");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 

  var ids = snapshot.val();
  console.log(ids.id);

});
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please post the full exception details

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the index to access

```
  var ref = db.ref("server/events/data");
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 

      var ids = snapshot.val();
      console.log(ids[0].id);

    });
```

Comment: @Suhaib you can use for loop or forEach for example check Frank answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Dinesh' answer is looping over all results:

```
var ref = db.ref("server/events/data");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var value = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(value.id);
  });
});
```

Or accessing only a specific index:

```
var ref = db.ref("server/events/data/0");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 
  var value = snapshot.val();
  console.log(value.id);
});
```

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for. Thanks for looking beyond my specific question